# CSS customization in Octostrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, octopress

I have an Octopress blog with an installed Octostrap3 theme. Everything works fine so far.

But I've been looking for the last days and I'm not able to find the responsible css files in **Octostrap3** to change the colors for my Octopress blog.

Could anybody tell me which css (or scss) files I need to edit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i've found a solution that works for me.

tomordonez' hint didn't help in my case (but thank you anyway), because there was just an screen.css in `/source/stylesheets`, no style.css.

If you have octostrap3 installed, you can use any bootstrap theme. To change the theme, you just have to edit the `/source/_includes/custom/head.html` and insert the path to the css file for your theme.

I placed my theme-css-file in `/source/assets/deg0nz/`, so i changed the head.html to:

```
<link href="{{ root_url }}/assets/deg0nz/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="{{ root_url }}/stylesheets/screen.css" media="screen, projection" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I have chosen a theme from [bootswatch](http://bootswatch.com/) and customized it with their [customization procedure](http://bootswatch.com/help/). So in the end i just had to change the bootswatch.less, the variables.less and the bootstrap.css in the bootswatch-theme folder and create the min-files.

Instead of doing this you can use any bootstrap.css and place it's path in `/source/_includes/custom/head.html` like i described above.

Answer (score 0):

Try source/stylesheets/style.css